# How to do the integral $\int \frac{d^{D}k}{(2\pi)^{D}} \frac{1-\cos(\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})}{k^2}$?

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, quantum-field-theory

In a lecture note (https://canvas.harvard.edu/courses/76589/files/folder/Lectures?), there is such kind of integral,
$$\int \frac{d^{D}k}{(2\pi)^{D}} \frac{1-\cos(\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})}{k^2}=\int \frac{d^{D}k}{(2\pi)^{D}}[ \frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{\cos(\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})}{k^2}]$$.
The author gives the answer in D=1 and D=2,
$$\int\frac{dk}{2\pi}\frac{1-\cos(kx)}{k^2}=-\frac{|x|}{2}\,\,(1)$$, and
$$\int^{\Lambda}\frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{1-\cos(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})}{k^2}\approx\frac{\ln(\Lambda|x|)}{2\pi},\,\,when\, |x|\to\infty\,\,(2)$$.

It seems that the cos term can be converted into a $\Gamma$ function, say
$$\int \frac{d^{D}k}{(2\pi)^{D}}\frac{e^{i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}}}{k^2}=\frac{2^{D-2}}{(4\pi)^{D/2}}\frac{1}{r^{D-2}}\Gamma(D/2-1)$$, when $D\to2$, it can be written as $\frac{1}{2\pi(D-2)}-\frac{1}{4\pi}(\gamma+\ln(\pi)+\ln(r^2))+O(D-2)$ (the method is similar to [An asymptotic expansion involving the gamma function in QFT](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035096/an-asymptotic-expansion-involving-the-gamma-function-in-qft), here is $2+\epsilon$, and there is $4-\epsilon$). Then the D=2 result may be "derived",
$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int^{\Lambda} d^{2}k\frac{1}{k^2}= \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(\Lambda)$$, and the only r dependent term in cos term is $-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(r)$, then $\int^{\Lambda}\frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{1-\cos(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})}{k^2}\approx\frac{\ln(\Lambda|x|)}{2\pi}$. Of course, there are still a divergent term $\frac{1}{2\pi(D-2)}$.

**But how to calculate the D=1 case?** And is there any other method to calculate such integral?

Comment: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1677090), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1057049), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/443056), etc.?

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks! They are helpful !

Comment: To the useful links provided by @metamorphy I would just add integration by part:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-\cos(kx)}{k^2}dk=\frac{\cos (kx)-1}{k}\,\bigg|_{-\infty}^\infty+x\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}dk=\pi x\operatorname {sgn} x=\pi|x|$$
The value is always positive; this is clear from the fact that the integrand is always positive    ($1-\cos (kx)\geqslant0$ at any $k, x\in R$).